# RegEx to capture execution time with specific text afterwards

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the follow log file that I am trying to parse.  I'm using regular expressions to gather the information I require and got most of it done.  I have a certain part of the log file that is repeated several times according to the step it was executed.  I could use the following regex and then return the capture array but the order of the steps could change.  I want to be able to capture the specific step with some assurance.

RegEx:

```
\[Total execution Time: (.+) min
```

Log Excerpt:

> 02/19 00:48:46:762 [INFO ] [MigrationWizard] [Total execution Time: 11.05 minute(s)] [administrator] [(null)] [14]
>   02/19 00:48:46:762 [INFO ] [MigrationWizard] [Total number of error(s): 0] [administrator] [(null)] [14]
>   02/19 00:48:46:762 [INFO ] [MigrationWizard] [Step 1 Done.] [administrator] [(null)] [14]

Do I need to use a look ahead assertion to make sure the total execution time is followed by a specific step name?  How do I account for all the characters in between?  How do I account for the multiple line feeds?  I'm using C#.

Comment: Are the three lines in your log excerpt always similar in the rest of your log? In other words, is the execution time of the step always followed by the name of the step two lines later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex

```
Total execution Time: ([\d.]+).*\r?\n.*\r?\n.*\[Step 1\s
```

Where "Step 1" of course needs to be changed for the step you desire to match. This will only match the total execution time of "Step 1".

Make sure singleline mode is not enabled (so the . does not match across newlines)

I assumed that the order of the log entries is always the same.

Comment: That did it.  Looking at the regex,  it looks like you are matching a certain number of carriage retruns after the total execution time.  I didn't think of that.  It might be the reason anything I tried failed to work.  Thanks!

Comment: There is no need for multiline mode as you are not using `^` or `$` - perhaps you mean: make sure singleline mode is _not_ enabled (so the `.` does not match across newlines). Also note that this will match `Step 10`, `Step 11` etc. unless your regex includes a trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
string strRegex = @"(Total execution Time: )(\d{2}[\.:]\d{2})\s+";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);

string strTargetString = @"..............";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // ........ do something
  }
}
```

Input string:

```
02/19 00:48:46:762 [INFO ] [MigrationWizard] [Total execution Time: 11.05 minute(s)] [administrator] [(null)] [14]
02/19 00:48:46:762 [INFO ] [MigrationWizard] [Total number of error(s): 0] [administrator] [(null)] [14]
02/19 00:48:46:762 [INFO ] [MigrationWizard] [Step 1 Done.] [administrator] [(null)] [14]
02/19 00:48:46:762 [INFO ] [MigrationWizard] [Total execution Time: 13:25 minute(s)] [administrator] [(null)] [14]
```

Matches:

```
Total execution Time: 11.05
Total execution Time: 13:25
```

Comment: I didn't want to iterate through the capture groups because steps can be omitted. In those cases the output would list steps values for incorrect steps. I format my output as "Step 1: 11.05 mins"

Answer (score 0):

Your regex

```
 \[Total execution Time: (.+) min
```

is inefficient as the `.+` will greedily match any character (except newlines) as many times as possible before backtracking to try to match the `" min"` following it. Better would be `.+?` which would match as few characters as possible before `" min"`, and better again would be to match just digits and the point `[\d.]+` or to match the specific format `\d\d\.\d\d`.

Anyway, to get the execution time when `[Step 1` is the next step following it, you could use, for example

```
Match m = Regex.Match(str,
    @"\[Total execution Time: ([\d.]+)(?:(?!\[Step ).)+\[Step 1 Done",
        RegexOptions.Singleline
);

if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);         
}
```

The negative look-ahead `(?!\[Step )` means the `.` will only match characters up until `"[Step "` appears in the string. `"[Step 1 Done"` must then be matched if the whole match is to be successful.

`RegexOptions.Singleline` is used so the `.` matches across newlines.

Alternatively, you could put the pattern before the `[\d.]+` in a positive look-behind and the pattern following it in a positive look-ahead and avoid the need to use a capture group to get the value, but it would make little difference to anything.

Comment: a bit more complicated than need be